# How can i execute an Observer after a controller Action?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer

I need to execute my observer just after an actionController end or when paymentMethod is saved on database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use `controller_action_postdispatch_<router_name>_<controller_name>_<action_name>` formula to derive the event name. You can also do this for predispatch aswell (Just replace `postdispatch` with `predispatch`).

**Core Example:**

Observing Magento Checkout Onepage controller saveOrderAction on the Paypal module:

`Mage_Checkout_OnepageController::saveOrderAction`

```
<router_name>: checkout
<controller_name>: onepage
<action_name>: saveOrder
```

Using the previous formula to create the event name to observe we finally end up with:

> Derived event name for our controller action method:

`controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder`

> Then in the *etc/config.xml*

```
<events>
    <controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder>
        <observers>
             <hss_save_order_onepage>
                 <class>paypal/observer</class>
                 <method>setResponseAfterSaveOrder</method>
             </hss_save_order_onepage>
         </observers>
    </controller_action_postdispatch_checkout_onepage_saveOrder>
</events>
```

> Getting the controller action in the Observer class:

```
/**
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 */
public function setResponseAfterSaveOrder(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    /* @var $controller Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action */
    $controller = $observer->getEvent()->getData('controller_action');

    // Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: When controller is not Mage, Router Name should include extension vendor. Eg. IWD_Opc_JsonController should be "controller_action_postdispatch_iwd_opc_json_saveBillingAddress" not as implied "controller_action_postdispatch_opc_json_saveBillingAddress"